# Kuratowski Embedding Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a quesion to the following proof of the Kuratowski Embedding theorem
on page 37/38.

https://books.google.at/books?id=k-m6CgAAQBAJ&pg=PR8&dq=topology+with+applications&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=topology%20with%20applications&f=false

especially to the following line:

"Then take the closure of the isometric image to obtain the completion of the metric space (X,d)."

My question is why is the closure of the isometric embedding the completion of (X,d)? How can I proof this?

Thank you for your Help.

Answer (score 1):

As its name says, the closure is closed in the Banach space, and a closed space in a complete space is complete. (If you take a Cauchy sequence in $X$, it will converge because it is in a Banach space, and it will converge in the closure of $X$ since this is closed, thus sequentially closed.)